# Adding links to a PHP array list?

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I never intended to have to use PHP - heck, two days ago I didn't even know what it *was*, so excuse me if any of my terminology is weird or incorrect.

My predicament is that I need a working code that will end up outputting a list of writer names (that's why the array is called "writers") that are linked to their writer pages/profiles. Here's what I have so far that correctly displays the list of writer names:

```
<?php
$writers = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'writer', false); 
$last  = array_slice($writers, -1);
$first = join(', ', array_slice($writers, 0, -1));
$both  = array_filter(array_merge(array($writers), $last), 'strlen');
echo join(' and ', $both);
?>
```

And the correct writer page link can be generated with this code:

```
<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'writerlink', true); ?>
```

I just don't have the skill to get these puzzle pieces to fit together. Since there are often multiple writers, there will often be more than one writer link. Is it possible to have each list/array value to have its correct link attached?

Comment: It is wordpress,  This looks like you have the first and last writers, correct.  and you want the links for them?  I particularly like this line `array_filter(array_merge(array($writers), $last), 'strlen');`  However this is not a list of all of them.  Last can be replaced with just `end($writers)` and first with `reset($wrtiers)`

Comment: And first is everything but the last one, I would do this with `array_pop()` instead of the 2 slices.  http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php  and `join` is `implode` lol, or an alias of it.  So you need the links for each one then?

Comment: is the key `writerlink` the same as $writers, for example is $writer[0] a key for the get_post_meta?    Otherwise then you only go by PostID and there is only a 1 to 1 relationship, and the writer will not matter.

Comment: Not gonna lie, I'm too new to understand what 99% of this means. But "writerlink" was just something I setup using a plugin so that info typed into the writerlink box on each post can be referred to with just "writerlink". And yes, I need the link for each one; like if I had it set up to list out like $writers[1], $writers[2], i could just circle each one with <a href="$writerlink[0]"></a> etc., but since I have it set up differently I'm not really sure what to try.

Comment: if `writerlink` is literally that text and not the value of $writers[0], then there is no relation between them and all you have is the postID, for example this call will be the same for each writer, `get_post_meta($post->ID, 'writerlink', true);` because the value of that $writer is not part of the call, make sense.  If you looped on `$writers` as `foreach($writers as $writer )` where in `get_post_meta($post->ID, 'writerlink', true);` is `$writer`...  if it's not, then there is no relationship between that variable and that function and the link is the same no matter the writer.